# Can binary strings in a terminal do anything dangerous?

Tags: terminal, binary-files

I find myself sometimes accidentally `cat`ing a binary file, or `SELECT`ing some binary field from the `mysql` CLI, ending up with stuff like this being displayed on the screen:

> ▒=▒▒▒▒f4▒Kҫ24T?)

Or worse (using `Putty` on Windows):

[image: Putty binary string]

The question is, apart from making my terminal potentially unusable (changing colors etc.), forcing me to close & reopen it, **is there any risk outputting binary data to a terminal?** Like getting a command executed by mistake, or anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: When `cat`ing a file, the possible side effects (as shown in user1686's answer) are what you asked for. The terminal should do its best not to suffer from serious problems, leaks, crashes etc., but you are also at least partially responsible if any problem happens. With CLI tools, however, like the mysql client, it's a different story. _They_ should be responsible for not printing anything to the terminal that they don't believe are safe. It should be filed as a bug against them.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73713/41467.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *some* risk that they could. In practice, terminal emulators nowadays try to ensure that all output is interpreted safely, but that's not quite 100% guaranteed – personally I'd say it is nowhere near as safe as giving untrusted HTML/JS to a web browser.

1. There are certain escape sequences which cause the terminal to **respond by sending some input** back to the program. ([This page](http://rtfm.etla.org/xterm/ctlseq.html) has a list of all common sequences – search for the word "Report".)

   For example, byte 0x05 (Ctrl+E) is control character ENQ, which has been obsolete for several decades, but in some terminals still generates a simple "answerback" sequence – `PuTTY` in this case.

   More commonly, programs might use a sequence that causes the terminal to answer with its current size (columns×lines) or report whether certain capabilities are supported (e.g. test for 256-color mode). Most of those sequences have responses in rigid format, but some can include free text, such as the "Report current window title" sequence.

   However, modern terminals generally make sure that these escape sequences never produce any "untrusted" input. That is, the console app can *set* the window title, but cannot *get* it back – the terminal will always respond as if the title was empty. Similarly, some terminals allow the console app to copy text to clipboard, but not to trigger pasting text back *from* clipboard.
2. There are certain escape sequences which are intended to **invoke actions** such as run a program, or show a notification, or move/resize the terminal window.

   In modern terminals, these are *mostly* safe – no terminal accepts "run program" anymore, and printing cannot be initiated either. But many terminals still allow the "move/resize" control sequences so untrusted output can actually make your PuTTY window zoom around the screen.

   Certain terminals such as Terminology have a few quite powerful custom control sequences which allow the app to embed a PNG image among text or even to display a video. So malicious binary output wouldn't need to rickroll you through grainy ASCII art, it could rickroll you in high-res.
3. Finally, a terminal's control sequence parser is a *complex* bit of code, and it's not impossible for it to have **security issues due to bugs** (e.g. buffer overflows). Don't forget to update PuTTY.

   And since even some "safe" sequences interact with the outside world, they could trigger OS bugs as well. For example, the sequence to display a system notification (which is otherwise a legitimate feature) could try to send HTML and some systems could actually interpret that HTML.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive and well-documented answer!

Answer (score 0):

`cat`ing should not do anything bad to your terminal, as it only "displays" the content of a file. As far as I can grab it, the same should apply to SQL statements.

What can happen is that the formatting of your console can break, if `cat` tries to print characters with special meanings accidentally (e.g. color codes). Then, all following lines and the input prompt may look awkward. But that should only be cosmetic.

That said, you should be careful as, depending on the sequence of events, user typed text can mix up with output text, which can obscure the current command. IMHO, it's usually more secure to exit those lines with `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: "That said, you should be careful if there is random text and you hit enter, because that is interpreted as a command then." Are you sure? As this is output and not input, even if I hit enter, I'd believe it should do nothing?

Comment: Well. It should be output, you are right. I think I wrote something different than I thought I wrote. I'll edit the answer.